# Is it possible to pass variables into an Emacs Org-Mode capture?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using emacs-24.3 for Windows and specifically Org-Mode, which is fantastic. I'm trying to setup a new capture template for defects that get handed me at work and would like the template to output something like this:

- TODO *description-of-defect*  *link-to-defect-in-jira*

e.g.

- TODO User having issue logging in to site COM-19112

The problem I am having is The URL is similar to this http://www.jira.com/browse/COM-19112 and I want it to be output as COM-19112. To do this normally in emacs I would do this:

```
[[http://www.jira.com/browse/COM-19112][COM-19112]]
```

However, when trying to setup an org capture template I only want to have to type COM-19112 once and it be filled in both places. Here is the best I can get so far - it gives me what I want but I have to type 'COM-19112' twice at prompt:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("d" "Defects" entry (file+headline "C:/EmacsOrg/Defects.org" "Tasks")
      "* TODO %? [[http://www.jira.com/browse/%^{Defect}][%^{Defect}]]")))
```

I can't see anything on http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#fn-2 that explains how to create a variable that can be used in multiple places but I am sure there is a way to do this.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Regards

BebopSong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page on [template expansion](http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html) does include information on how to re-insert an existing variable.

```
 %\n         Insert the text entered at the nth %^{prompt}, where n is
             a number, starting from 1.
```

Assuming your template is as above:

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("d" "Defects" entry (file+headline "C:/EmacsOrg/Defects.org" "Tasks")
      "* TODO %? [[http://www.jira.com/browse/%^{Defect}][%^{Defect}]]")))
```

You can replace it with

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("d" "Defects" entry (file+headline "C:/EmacsOrg/Defects.org" "Tasks")
      "* TODO %? [[http://www.jira.com/browse/%^{Defect}][%\\1]]")))
```

You may need to change the `%\\1` depending on what other variables are being defined.  (It does require the double backslash to work since `\` is an escape character)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I misunderstood the explanation on the page so thank you for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar case for which I use code similar to the following:

```
(defun org-at-special (type)
  "Check whether point is at a special link of the form [[TYPE:address]]
TYPE is given as string.
Returns the address."
  (save-excursion
    (when (and (looking-back (concat "\\[\\[\\(?:" type "\\([^][\n\r]+\\)?\\]\\[\\)?[^]]*\\(\\]\\)?"))
           (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
           (looking-at (concat "\\[\\[" type "\\([^][\n\r]+\\)\\]")))
      (match-string-no-properties 1))))

(require 'browse-url)

(defun org-open-google ()
  (let ((q (org-at-special "google:")))
    (when q
      (apply browse-url-browser-function  (list (concat "http://www.google.com/#q=" q)))
      t)))

(add-to-list 'org-open-at-point-functions 'org-open-google)
```

After this definition you can put links like `[[google:stackoverflow]]` into your org-file.
You only need to define your own `org-open-google` function which then may be named `org-open-defect` or however you like it. You have to add this name to the list `org-open-at-point-functions`.

I did some modifications for you. Therefore, the above code is not heavily tested. But, I did already some basic tests.

If the prefix is always COM- you can already take this as type for `org-at-special` then links like `[[COM-19112]]` are reckognized and you have exactly the display you want. Your special case would then be something like that:

```
(defun org-open-COM- ()
  (let ((q (org-at-special "COM-")))
    (when q
      (apply browse-url-browser-function  (list (concat "http://www.jira.com/browse/COM-" q)))
      t)))

(add-to-list 'org-open-at-point-functions 'org-open-COM-)
```

After that a capture like the following is sufficient

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("d" "Defects" entry (file+headline "/c/temp/Defects.org" "Tasks")
      "* TODO %? [[COM-%^{Defect}]]")))
```

Therewith, you only need to input the defect number once.

Comment: Why not using org-link-abbrev-alist for your custom links?

Comment: @user2708138 - I had an issue with the org-open-at-point-functions list. My emacs file wouldn't load saying the variable was void.

Comment: @fniessen - Thanks for showing me that. I will use those useful link abbreviations in the future however they did not answer my question because I'd have to write the defect number in the tag and description to get the true link. Otherwise I'd get a link that looked like this: jira:COM-19912.

Comment: @BebopSong: With `M-x org-version` == 8.0.5 the variable `org-open-at-point-functions` is defined in `org.el`. That means `(require 'org)` on top of all the stuff above should work. I assumed that you had something like that already in your initialization. Maybe, you only need to change the order.